# How to go from child UIViewController to parent UIViewController and from there to another child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent UIViewController(`MainVC`). From there I have 2 segue to 2 UIViewControllers: `FirstVC` (identifier: `goFirstVC`) and `SecondVC` (identifier: `goSecondVC`)
In `FirstVC` I have a button `Save` and when I click it I want to dismiss the `FirstVC` and to go on `SecondVC`.

Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

   //navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

   let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goSecondVC") as! SecondVC
    let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { () -> Void   in
    presentingVC!.present(destinationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Here is the design for my issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setViewControllers` to keep the parent only and the SecondVC

```
let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goSecondVC") as! SecondVC

self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first!,destinationController], animated: true)
```

Comment: `goSecondVC` is the storyboard identifier of the second vc or segue name ?

Comment: Error is  this: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
And `goSecondVC` is the segue name.

Comment: it should be storyborad identifier

Comment: I just gave to storyboard the same name and is also crashing with the same error in console.

Comment: Works perfect. Was a conflict of names because I was using the same name for Segue and StoryboardID. Thank you Sh_Khan.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods but one of the generic one is to use delegates and protocols. Use the following code in your classes.

Add Following code in the first VC

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate : AnyObject {
   func goToSecondVC()
}
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    var Delegate : SecondVCDelegate!
     @objc func save() {
         Delegate.goToSecondVC()
    }
 }
//In second view
```

Add following code in MinVC

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidAppear() {
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: <yourSegueIdentifierToFirstVC>, sender: nil)

        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == <yourSegueIdentifierToFirstVC> {
                let cont = segue.destination as! FirstVC
                cont.Delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
    extension MainVC : SecondVCDelegate {
        func goToSecondVC() {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: <yourSegueIdentifierToSecondVC>, sender: nil)
        }
    }
    //This is MainVC
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you should present second from first rather than dismissing first then presenting second.
- when you will present second from first then if you wanto go back to main you can simply dismiss 2 veiwcontrollers at once without any hack.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

We can control our presented controllers with navigation controller calling `pushViewController` and `popViewController` methods.

```
FirstVC.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated) //  pops the top view controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondVC, animated: true) //  Pushes a view controller onto navigation's stack of controllers
```

In your case:

```
let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goSecondVC") as? SecondVC
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController, animated: true)
```